# How to change compareProducts view page layout in magento2

Tags: magento2, layout

[image]

**I want to change the product compare page layout form 1column to 2column-left please give me suggestions**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `root directory\app\design\frontend\namespace\themename\Magento_Catalog\layout` folder and open `catalog_product_compare_index.xml` file

if there is no `catalog_product_compare_index.xml` file then copy it from `root directory\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\layout`

now change **layout="2columns-left"** in `catalog_product_compare_index.xml`

see this:
https://www.screencast.com/t/AQHWIMoU4

**note:** clear your cache

Comment: Most welcome !! @mohammadmahamoodali